# Debug HTTPS hanging in Pulse Secure SSL VPN Tunnel

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, vpn, https

I have a Pulse VPN Client running in Ubuntu 18.04 and facing problems when connecting over HTTPS to websites over the VPN. SSH and ping work fine.

Chrome and Firefox both hang, 'Establishing secure connection' and 'Performing TLS handshahe'.

I tried using `openssl` to check the `https`

```
robau@ubuntu:~$ openssl s_client -connect jira.mycompany.local:443
CONNECTED(00000005)
```

After `CONNECTED` there is no more output.

What can I do to debug what is going wrong?

Comment: My guess is that this is an MTU problem. See also https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/737c1z/friendly_reminder_if_ssh_sometimes_hangs/

Comment: @SteffenUllrich you are right! Setting the MTU to 1000 worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

If certain ICMP `Fragmentation needed` messages are blocked, then you can have this problem. SSL handshakes tends to use large packets early in a connection, so they are something of a canary in the coalmine for this. Nice article about IPsec overheads: https://packetpushers.net/ipsec-bandwidth-overhead-using-aes/. IPv6 traffic uses an extra 20 bytes for its ip header, and also REQUIRES a minimum MTU of 1280, so a tunnel with MTU 1000 would disqualify for IPv6.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is the problem (how can I verify that?), but many thanks for the nice read!

Comment: Cloudflare as usual has a very good writeup about this. They even have a tricked out testing page for this. http://icmpcheck.popcount.org/ and commandline tests described in https://blog.cloudflare.com/ip-fragmentation-is-broken/

Answer (score 0):

As Steffen already mentioned in the comments, it seems it is an MTU issue.

I solve it by running this after setting up the tunnel:

```
 sudo ifconfig tun0 mtu 1000
```

The default setting of my tunnel was a MTU of 1400, when comparing to Windows users' settings we saw they use a MTU of 1240.

### Edit

I found the MTU is calculated by getting the minimum MTU from the other connections, and subtracting 100 from that.

Reference:
 https://community.pulsesecure.net/t5/Pulse-Connect-Secure/Manually-Set-MTU-for-Network-Connect-Pulse/td-p/40593

### Even more info:

Then I found more specific information on calculating the MTU in newer and older versions of Pulse.

> In the earlier Pulse client releases, i.e. prior to v5.2R2, the
>   virtual adapter MTU was calculated based on the physical adapter MTU
>   (of the host machine) and the MTU sent by the PCS.
>
> Basically the formula used to calculate the virtual adapter MTU is:
>
> MIN (Physical Adapter MTU, MTU from PCS, TCP MSS value + 40)

https://docs.pulsesecure.net/WebHelp/PCS/9.0R3/AG/Content/PCS/PCS_AdminGuide_9.0R3/Using_the_Advanced_Client.htm

I can't find other resources, so if anyone has more info, that is most welcome!